# how can I increment json value in Typescript example increment likes or dislikes on button clicks

Tags: json, angular, typescript

how can I increment json value in Typescript example increment likes or dislikes on button clicks.[image]

```
movies: any[] = [
   { name: "Fan", likes: 0, dislikes: 0, unseen: 0, fimage: "/images/fan.jpg" },
   { name: "Airlift", likes: 0, dislikes: 0, unseen: 0, fimage: "/images/airlift.jpg" },
   { name: "Wazir", likes: 0, dislikes: 0, unseen: 0, fimage: "/images/wazir.jpg" },
   { name: "Neerja", likes: 0, dislikes: 0, unseen: 0, fimage: "/images/neerja.jpg" },
   { name: "Bajirao mastani", likes: 0, dislikes: 0, unseen: 0, fimage: "/images/bajirao.jpg" }
];
```

Comment: Cany ou share some of your code you got so far, the important typescript and html pieces?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that your list looks something like this in the HTML, you first need to listen for the click events:

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies">
    ...
    <div class="like" (click)="onLike(movie)">...</div>
    <div class="dislike" (click)="onDislike(movie)">...</div>
</div>
```

With the above-shown template, you loop over every `movie` in the `movies` array. You also have to bind `click` events to the like and dislike button to know when the user clicked one of them.

**Typescript**

```
export class MoviesComponent {

    movies: any[] = [
        { name: "Fan", likes: 0, dislikes: 0, unseen: 0, fimage: "/images/fan.jpg" },
        { name: "Airlift", likes: 0, dislikes: 0, unseen: 0, fimage: "/images/airlift.jpg" },
        { name: "Wazir", likes: 0, dislikes: 0, unseen: 0, fimage: "/images/wazir.jpg" },
        { name: "Neerja", likes: 0, dislikes: 0, unseen: 0, fimage: "/images/neerja.jpg" },
        { name: "Bajirao mastani", likes: 0, dislikes: 0, unseen: 0, fimage: "/images/bajirao.jpg" }
    ];

    onLike(movie) {
        // find the movie in the movies array
        const index = this.movies.indexOf(movie);
        // update the movie
        this.movies[index].likes++;
    }

    onDislike(movie) {
        // find the movie in the movies array
        const index = this.movies.indexOf(movie);
        // update the movie
        this.movies[index].dislikes++;
    }

}
```

You simply increment the likes or dislikes when the user clicked on one of the buttons.
It would probably be a good idea to give each movie a unique id to find it more safely in the array.

Please let me know if this helped!

Comment: I am glad I helped you! If this solved your problem please check the arrow left to my answer :)